how to remove crystal report 2011 blank rows in between subreports
When I export the crystal report as excel (data only), there will be blank rows between the subreports, have suppressed / hide the unrequired rows of the subreports (page header, page footer etc)  was expecting to be a seamless join of subreports without any blank rows. Is there a work around this? or does all main report which consist of multiple subreports will have these blank rows in between them?
Exported Report in excel

afaik, there is no way to avoid that problem. But you can work around it.
In my Crystal Reports automation software, I have an option to delete empty rows in Excel (Data Only) exports.  The code takes care of that as an immediate step AFTER the export. You can do the same.
